# Flask app on WebApp not calling expected function

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have a flask app that I deployed on Azure WebApp.

Before creating the app, I am calling a function which would set some secrets, one time, for each request to use.

Here is the snippet:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_secrets():
    try:
        # getting and setting secrets
        return True
    except (Exception,) as e:
        return False


@app.route("/my-endpoint", methods=["POST"])
def endpoint():
    # do something


def start_app():
    successful_secret_retrieval = get_secrets()
    if successful_secret_retrieval:
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=9090)
    else:
        print("Failed to retrieve secrets")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_app()
```

This works fine in my local. It would first set the secrets, create the app and when I call my endpoint, it uses the same variables.

But in Azure WebApp, it does not call `get_secrets` function, it just creates and starts the app.

I want to set the secrets first and then start the app in WebApp as well, just like how it is behaving in local.

How to do that?

Comment: Could you provide me what type of secret you are trying to retrieve ?

Comment: Where are these secrets coming from? Are you reading environmental variables? Or, if you are only getting and setting them once, can you make them environmental variables?

Comment: I am getting secrets from **Azure Key Vault**.

Answer (score 1):

In Azure Web App, the application server manages the lifecycle of your Flask application. The initialization and configuration process may differ from your own local development environment.

To ensure that your function is called before your Flask app starts, you can use the application factory pattern. This involves creating a separate function to create and configure your Flask app, allowing you to perform any necessary setup before running the app. Here's an example:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # Perform any necessary setup, including getting and setting secrets
    successful_secret_retrieval = get_secrets()
    
    if not successful_secret_retrieval:
        raise Exception("Failed to retrieve secrets")
    
    @app.route("/my-endpoint", methods=["POST"])
    def endpoint():
        # Your endpoint logic here
    
    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=9090)
```

Comment: Guapi-zh, thanks for your reply. My app run depends on the secrets. If retrieval of secret got failed, app should not even get created.

Comment: I tried this in Azure Web App but got below error (multiline error) - 
`Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app'.
Shutting down: Master
Reason: App failed to load.
ERROR - Container <container-name> for site <site-name> has exited, failing site start`

Comment: I remember Azure uses "gunicorn" by default. As we're using the application factory pattern, we can specify a function call like my_project:create_app(). You can skip making an app.py file and create your app directly: ```gunicorn -w 4 "my_project:create_app()"```

Comment: I need to use app.py. Any other alternative?